# Windows Recycle Bin ICON notification

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I need to notify Windows Explorer to refresh its Recycle Bin ICON after programmatically deleting its contents so that it will show the empty recycle bin icon. How do I do that in  using vc++.

Comment: Are you using `SHEmptyRecycleBin()` to empty the recycle bin? I think this function is supposed to update the icon when it's done.

Comment: Yes... but If I do that it will also automatically delete all contents and I don t want that functionality because I want to examine If any file has been missed by my program.. I only want the notification.

Comment: You should be programmatically deleting items via `IFileOperation`, in which case the recycle bin will update automatically. (And I don't understand what you mean by "examine if any file has been missed by my program".)

Comment: @A.K: so you want to delete items from the Recycle Bin without actually deleting the files themselves? What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau when files are seen to be in Recycle Bin their actully on the partition they belonged before being deleted in a folder called $Recycle or something like that.. If you delete those.. in that path X:\$Recycle... the Virtual Folder (which RBin is) won t get updated immediately .. only if u enter it and so it sees that it has no files ..and so on.

Comment: @A.K. All the more reason why you should tell the Recycle Bin itself to delete individual files, such as via `IFileOperation` like Raymond Chen saId, rather than delete the files yourself and then tell the Recycle Bin to update itself.

Comment: You are very right indeed..

Comment: It seems I'm not having the best of luck with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810755/delete-shell-forlder-contents-using-ifileoperation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell32.dll exports a function called `SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon` which does just what it says. This function isn't documented but you can call it like this:

```
typedef void (WINAPI* PFNSHUPDATERECYCLEBINICON)();
PFNSHUPDATERECYCLEBINICON pfnFunc = (PFNSHUPDATERECYCLEBINICON)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"shell32.dll"), "SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon");
if (pfnFunc) pfnFunc();
```

I'd take note of other comments though that deleting things from the recycle bin yourself isn't probably best practice (and nor, of course, is using undocumented functions).

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess: You are emptying it by manually removing the files inside the actual recycle bin folder?

Have you tried [SHEmptyRecycleBin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762160%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

This is the call Windows Explorer uses to empty the bin, it should take care of the icon ;)

Comment: just the notification.. I insist on that.